# How to fix " Gradle error : Network is unreachable: connect " In Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

when i want to sync my project i see this error message:

ERROR: Network is unreachable: connect
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I already uninstall and install several times and, I also try several versions of gardle and android studio, I reinstall the SDK
always the same problem

AndroidStudio version: 3.3

SDK: Android Pie 28

Gradle : 4.10.1
[Capture Of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bESNQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think HTTP Proxy settings causes to this problem. Check your HTTP settings in android studio.